# How to create a HeatMap using country borders with Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-basemap

[image]

I wanted to know if there is any way possible of making a heatmap like the above, i.e. on a real map(like the above), in matplotlib or any other python library.

Comment: there are lots of ways to do this. they greatly vary based on how the boundaries are stored.

Answer (score 0):

You can use matplotlib-basemap, which is an extension to matplotlib.
Look at the really well done [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html) first.
If you have questions after reading it you may update your question.